# why preg_match() does not match in some cases

Tags: php, preg-match

Here I'm using a code which works for all  other input but not for `hospital` **why?**

If you suggest any other filter then this it will be much appreciated.

See the demo:  http://phpio.net/s/cgv

Here is my code:

```
$type = strtolower("hospital"); 

if(preg_match('/it|IT|it services|it service|it infrastructure|it infrastructures/',$type)){
    $img = "images/it1-200x111.jpg";
}else if(preg_match('/business|business solutions|biz solutions|business solution|biz solution/',$type)){
    $img = "images/business-200x111.jpg";
}else if(preg_match('/manpower|manpower solution|manpower solutions|manpower services|manpower service|human resource|human resources/',$type)){
    $img = "images/mp-1-200x111.jpg";
}else if(preg_match('/financial|finance|financial solution|financial solutions|financial service|financial services/',$type)){
    $img = "images/fin-200x111.jpg";
}else if(preg_match('/marketing|marketing solution|marketing solutions|marketing service|marketing services/',$type)){
    $img = "images/mark1-200x111.jpg";
}else if(preg_match('/real estate|real estates|real estate solution|real estates solution|real estate solutions/',$type)){
    $img = "images/real1-200x111.jpg";
}else if(preg_match('/school|schooling services|school services|schools service|schooling service/',$type)){
    $img = "images/school1-200x111.jpg";
}else if(preg_match('/college|college service|college services|colleges/',$type)){
    $img ="images/coll1-200x111.jpg";
}else if(preg_match('/hospital|hospitals|hospital service|hospital services/',$type)){
    $img = "images/hosp-1-200x111.jpg";
}else{
    $img = "images/it1-200x111.jpg";
}

echo $img;
```

Comment: You mean when hospital will be in URL..it is not working ..?

Comment: because there is a `it` on `hospital`

Comment: $type determines which condition to enter but it is not enter hospital section, others it is entering

Comment: I think it would be better if you use in_array() for each if you have there...

Comment: @EaBangalore, yes, because it matches with `it`. try to change it to `^it`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Here you can see the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hospital` matches your first condition because there is `it` there.
Try add start/beginning symbol `^` on the conditions. For example `^it`, it will only match when string starts with `it`.

Comment: can i have demo on phpio.net